# ImportError: No module named 'Cython' when installing requirements on readthedocs server

Tags: cython, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'd like to use an extension to autogenerate the output of examples in code snippets for readthedocs. I have found a module that does this, sphinx-autorun. However, when I try to install all the modules required by my package (in the requirements for readthedocs) I get an error in the build log of readthedocs, namely:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-tsfmsady/clustertree/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
```

Any tips on how to fix this? I have the following options set:

[image]

[image]

Comment: is cython in your requirements file?

Comment: you may also want to try the conda-based builds on readthedocs, especially if your package has dependencies that need to be compiled

Comment: Sounds like something did not install on RTD that is installed in your local environment. Try cloning your repo into a clean checkout, then repeating the commands that RTD invokes to build the docs. There might also be something not in your requirements.txt file that you expect to be present in RTD, but is not.

Comment: @ngoldbaum Yes, and thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @StevePiercy Good idea, I'll try that after the conda based builds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conda-based build worked for me.

You can put a readthedocs.yml in the root folder of your repo (not your docs folder):

```
requirements_file:
  docs/requirements.txt

conda:
    file: environment.yml
```

My conda environment.yml:

```
channels:
- conda-forge
- bioconda
- r
- jkroes
dependencies:
- cython
- python=3.6
- numpy
- pandas
- sphinx-autorun=1.1.0=py36h5809654_0
```

You can even have a pip-section in the conda yaml:

```
channels:
- conda-forge
- bioconda
- r
- jkroes
dependencies:
- cython
- python=3.6
- numpy
- pandas
- pip:
    - clustertree
    - pyranges
    - sphinx_autorun_ebs
    - pyrle
    - sorted_nearest
```